# Merging changes from master into my branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge

I have two branches in git: `master` and `custom_branch`.

Somebody added some code to `master` that I need to use in my `custom_branch`. I tried this:

```
git branch custom_branch
git merge master
```

But when I do that, it says:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

But, when I compare `master` and `custom_branch`, the changes are still not there. What am I missing?

P.S. I don't want to `rebase` since other people also use this branch.

Comment: Because with the command that you provided `git branch custom_branch` you don't change to `custom_branch` just staying on `master`. Execute `git checkout custom_branch` and if the master have some changes in master after you created the `custom_branch` then if you want to merge the changes to your `custom_branch` execute `git merge master`.

Comment: I already suggested this in my answer, but he seems to have an issue with git not recognizing changes.

Comment: having the same issue. Have rebased and tried merging multiple times. git says up to date but the changes are not merging to my custom_branch. I can see the changes when i checkout the master branch.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

`git checkout custom_branch && git rebase master`

This will update `custom_branch` with changes from `master` branch.

Don't forget to make sure `master` is up to date first. `git pull`

---

This is also possible with `git checkout custom_branch && git merge master`

---

For an explanation on why the first one is (probably) what you should be using: [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to rebase since others are also using this branch. Also, running the second command says everything is already up to date.

Comment: @Darth.Vader have you ran `git pull` before attempting to merge?

Comment: After doing this I get this message "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart." What should I do?

Comment: @OllieWilliams Did you rebase after pushing your branch to origin? Better to merge.

Answer (score 102):

`git merge master` will update your current branch with the changes from your **local** master branch, the state of which will be that of when you last pulled while on that branch.

I think this is what you are looking for: `git merge origin master`

Comment: Hi. Does this work if I switch to main first and pull? 
$ git checkout main
$ git pull
$ git checkout feature branch
$ git merge main
$ git push

Comment: If you switch to `main` first and pull, you can then use `git merge main` with no problem. The issue is that the `main` on your local system is no longer current with the remote main. The checkout/pull you mentioned would take care of that. Doing `git merge origin master` means you won't have to checkout/pull main first.

Answer (score 29):

Answering my own question but to pull changes from upstream's master into my custom branch I did this:

```
git pull [URL TO UPSTREAM'S REPO] master
```

In the end I did,

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 11):

Just do:

```
git fetch origin master
```

And then do:

```
git merge master
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably still have to pull the changes to your local master branch. Before your commands, use
`git checkout master` and then
`git pull`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you're on the branch you want to merge into. Command for merging master into the

`git merge master && git commit -m "merging master" && git push`